# Listing textual entries of the form \[ ]

Tags: functions, text

How do I create a full list of textual entries for symbols of the form `\[Integral]`, `\[Sum]`, and so on?

Comment: On `Windows` we have a `ListingOfNamedCharacters.nb` which is part of the documentation, you can parse the file with the following code to get all the entries: `Cases[NotebookImport[path,"GuideText"],Cell[x_,"InlineCharacterName",___]:>x,Infinity]`. On my machine it was in the `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Wolfram Research\Documentation.en-us\13.1\Documentation\English\System\Guides` directory. (as of 13.1, we have 1061 entries)

Comment: [`Listing of Named Characters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon:  That's it.  Thanks very much.